# Android. Error in onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-activity, camera

I have created activity, which offers standard program the camera device. After you create pictures, it is stored in phone memory and the name of the pictures into the database. The problem is that if you create a few photos, then the name of a photo and record in the database do not match.
For example:
That stack:

```
10-21 20:22:37.617: I / System.out (22 016): Debug - name of foto - 70,134,596
10-21 20:22:45.195: I / System.out (22 016): Debug - name of foto - 89,410,152
10-21 20:22:45.382: I / System.out (22 016): Debug - name of database record - 89,410,152
```

In this case, created a photo with the name - 70134596, but the database gets a record number - 89410152. Here's the code:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
        File photo = null;

        date = (int) (Math.random() * 100000000);

        photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/DebtorMini", date + ".jpg");
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));

        imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
        System.out.println("Debug - name of foto - " + date);

        startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
        case TAKE_PICTURE:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri selectedImage = imageUri;
                getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);
                ImageView imageView = new ImageView(ctx);
                setContentView(imageView);
                ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
                Bitmap bitmap = null;

                try {
                    bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media
                            .getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                Toast.makeText(this, selectedImage.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                DataBaseHelper helper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
                try {
                    helper.createDataBase();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
                String category = extras.getString("category");
                String address = extras.getString("address");

                Toast.makeText(
                        this,
                        "Фотография успешно создана категория - " + category
                                + "  адресс - " + address, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                helper.openDataBase();
                helper.exec("INSERT INTO 'photos' (`id`, `address`, `category`) VALUES ('"
                        + date + "', '" + address + "', '" + category + "')");
                System.out.println("Debug - name of database record - " + date);

                helper.close();
            }
        }

    }
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that your date field is getting set to a new random number when you return to the activity you have posted. Put a breakpoint in your onCreate function and I suspect its getting called more than once. Most likely this is due to a rotation of your phone.

That being said, you should really just be querying the media provider to get the name of the file the media was stored in. Alternatively, you should persist your date field with onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState.

**EDIT**

```
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(mediaUri, new String[] { MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA }, null,null,null);
if(c != null) { 
    try {
        if(c.moveToFirst()) {
            String fullFilePath = c.getString(0); 
            String fileName = new File(fullFilePath).getName();
        }
    } finally { 
         c.close();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but you can sample as querying the media provider to get the name of the last file the media was stored in?